# is this the correct way to 'stop' a thread gracefully?

Tags: java, multithreading

instead of continuous checking of variable inside a loop:

```
class Tester {
    public static void main() {
        Try t = new Try();
        Thread.sleep(10); //wait for 10 milliseconds
        t.interrupt(); // 'interrupt' i.e stop the thread
    }
}

public class Try extends Thread {
    public void interrupt() {
        //perform all cleanup code here
        this.stop();
        /*stop() is unsafe .but if we peform all cleanup code above it should be okay ???. since thread is calling stop itself?? */
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit the code in your post to be readable and also make sure to ask the question in the body of your post.

Comment: I have formatted your code and make it compilable (`try` is not a valid class name...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Thread.interrupt()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt%28%29) method instead of Thread.stop(). In the interrupted thread you can catch the `InterruptedException` and do any cleanup required.

A similar questions has already been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5915156/how-can-i-kill-a-thread-without-using-stop/5915306#5915306), you can find a code sample there too.

Answer (score 1):

In order to perform interrupt in a good manner you should poll for the "interrupted()" method inside the thread that is being interrupted. 
Just be aware that calling interrupted() method resets the interruption flag (that is set when calling interrupt()).

I guess the bottom line is that you have to continuously poll inside the thread in order to perform a graceful interruption.

Answer (score 1):

**You should never ever call .stop() on a Thread, period.** It's not enough for the thread to perform its own cleanup. Since calling .stop() immediately releases all monitors, other threads may see shared data in an inconsistent state which may result in almost impossible to track errors.