# wait and notify with condition Java

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I am using wait and notify() methods for first time and I tried in this way.

sample codes

```
public class Tester
{
static boolean closing == false;
static int n;
DateTime dt = new DateTime();
int getMin = dt.getMinuteOfDay(); //minute of the day
int tempMin = dt.getMinuteOfDay()+5;// minute of the day + 5 minutes

public static void setClosing(boolean b)
{
    closing = b;        
}

public static int getN()
{
    return n;
}

class notifier extends Thread 
{
    public void run()
    {
        synchronized(this)
        {
            while(getMin == tempMin || closing == true)
            {
                notify();
            }
        }
    }
}

public void starter() throws InterruptedException 
{        
    notifier nn = new notifier();
    while(n==1)
    {
        notify.start();
        if(closing == false)
        {
            synchronized(notify)
            {
                nn.wait();
                mailreader();
                getMin = getMin+5;
                tempMin = tempMin+5;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            n=2;
        }
    }
}
}
```

main class

```
public class Tester2 extends WindowAdapter
{
public Tester2()
{        
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.addWindowListener(this);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    Tester t = new Tester();
    t.starter();
}

@Override
public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e)
{
    Tester.setClosing(true);
    while(Tester.getN() != 2)
    {
        //wait
    }
    frame.dispose();        
}

public static void main(String args[])
{
    Tester2 t = new Tester2();        
}    
}
```

I am calling **mailreader()** method for every 5minutes to perform some task, but

when user closes the Jframe  the  **closing** is set to true from main class i want to come out of the while loop in **notifier** class.

All I am trying to do here is, when user closes the JFrame, i don't want the mailreader() to be stopped in middle and exit, instead i want the JFrame to wait until the method is finished and then close or if it is waiting mode(notifier class) i want to come to out of it and exit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want to do is have something run periodically in a background thread, then get canceled in an orderly manner when the application closes, you don't need all this. Instead you can make a Runnable that loops, sleeping and doing its mail-reading, which quits when interrupted (the Runnable can control when it handles the interrupt so it's not in the middle of something). Once you start the thread, have the GUI keep a reference to it so it can call interrupt on it when closing.

Here's [an example of how to cancel a thread using interrupt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5915306/217324).