# How to make a Java program that will interrupt a thread.sleep() if the mouse is clikced?

Tags: java

I have a Thread.sleep(100) line in my program. I want to interrupt the Thread.sleep if the mouse is clicked. What code would I write to do that?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1036754/difference-between-wait-and-sleep

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/5915306/217324

Answer (score 1):

Basically - don't. This is one of the reasons why `Thread.sleep` is discouraged. You should change it to a [BlockingQueue.poll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html#poll%28long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29)

```
// Thread.sleep(100);
blockingQueue.poll(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

now you can stop the pause by pushing something into the blockingqueue at the other end.

You may even discover that you can increase the timeout too.