# How to ask while to stop from another class

Tags: java

There is the class:

```
public class M16
 {
  public boolean on = true;
  void shoot ()
  {
    System.out.println("Bang");
  }
  void pullTrigger()
  {
    while(on) shoot();
  }
 }
```

And I want to set my flag ON after i call pullTrigger() method. Like this:

```
    M16 m = new M16();
    m.pullTrigger();
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    m.on = false;
```

It is simple question, but i dont know what I need to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually cannot interrupt `while` from the same `Thread`. `Thread.sleep(2000)` will never be executed because `m.pullTrigger()` runs forever. Your scenario is more likely to happen in a multi-thread setup. There are [numerous SO topics covering this area](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D%20stop%20thread), for example [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5915156/).