# Java - terminating a method within a Thread

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a `Java` thread with a run method that computes many things. You can think of it as a series of math statements as follows. Note that each computation may utilize other methods that in turn might have additional loops and such.

```
public void run() {
   [computation 1 goes here here that takes a few seconds]
   [computation 2 goes here that takes a few seconds]
   ....
   [computation 30 goes here that takes a few seconds]
}
```

There is a `GUI` that prints the output of these statements as they produce their results, and I'd like the user to be able to say "Stop" whenever they want. Here are two methods I thought of

---

**Method 1: Many Boolean Checks [LOOKS TERRIBLE]**

```
private boolean stop;
public void run() {
   if(!stop)
       [computation 1 goes here here that takes a few seconds]
   if(!stop)
       [computation 2 goes here that takes a few seconds]
   ....
   if(!stop)
       [computation 30 goes here that takes a few seconds]
}
```

In this method, once the stop flag has been set to true, the computations will end. Note how silly this looks, having 30 `if` statements. Importantly, the critical question here is how often to put these conditions. Note that the computations on each line are not necessarily a single line. Taken to the extreme, does EVERY line in the `run()` method deserve a `if(!stop)` call above it? This doesn't seem like good design.

**Method 2: Generalizing Computations [CANNOT DO THIS]**

```
pirivate boolean stop;
public void run() {
   for(int i = 0; i < computationsN && !stop; i++) {
       computuations.get(i).compute();
}
```

I imagine that this method will be suggested, so I'd like to simply state that it is impossible in my case, given the sheer variation in the lines that I am calling "computations" for simplicity. I have typically done this for threads that are basic `while` loops, and it works great for such. But not in this case when the `run()` method is simply a huge method of variable code.

---

Any other solutions out there? Seems like this should be a universal problem. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Catch InterruptedException, throw an interrupt at the thread...?

Comment: throw an interrupt at the thread? what do you mean?

Comment: At first thought, it seems like (at the very least), Method 1 could be prettified by putting computations within a general class, and stuffing them in an array. Iterate through the array, and check a stop flag after each calculation. Edit: nevermind! I just realized that's what your Method 2 addressed.  Sorry! :)  But this looks relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5915156/how-can-i-kill-a-thread-without-using-stop

Comment: Yep! :) That's why I included Method 2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

what you want to do actually could be done with method 2, but you have to use the [Strategy Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern), is really the one more thing you need, because it make it possible to simplify your computations in one single line, like you actually did in Method 2.

It works like this, it lets you to change the next executable algorithm by doing polymorphism.

[image]

So first you have to make all your algorithms in different classes and each one has to implement one interface (it could be called `Computable` ) with one single method, that is, your `compute()` method.

Ex.

```
public interface Computable {
    public void compute();
}
```

And your Algorithms classes could be something like:

```
  public class AlgorithmX implements Computable {

    @Override
    public void compute() {
        // TODO Your Real Computation here for the Algorithm X
    }
  }
```

Then in your `for` Loop your `computations` Collection (or Array) is populated with Objects that implements `Computable`, i.e., with your Algorithms Objects.

```
for(int i = 0; i < computations && !stop; i++) {
   computuations.get(i).compute();
}
```

So you are in the right path with Method 2, I hope your way is more clear now.

Cheers!

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however I realize that this is simply a fancier way of doing Method 2. But I assure you, there is little similarity between my "compute" lines. I simply called them computations for simplicity of the question...I don't think grouping them in this regard is logical in my case.

Comment: CodeGuy, they don't necessarily need to be similar computations to use this pattern. The constructors for the various classes could all take different arguments. Can you give one example of compute 1 and 2 that would not allow this pattern to be used?

Comment: it doesnt matter how similar or dissimilar the compute lines are. using "method 2" abstracts them into callable "things". if you dont want to do that you will need all those if statements. there really aren't any other options. there are many benefits to abstracting these calculations to their own classes. you can apply other standard features, such as counting how many have run. applying standard failure mechanisms etc. you can load them into queues and process them in different ways.

Comment: You could do anything you want inside each compute method, I though it could be useful in this case, but anyway I am out of your business context.

Comment: Your idea is useful, but just not what I was looking for. Thanks though!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a `stop` flag you can call `interrupt()` on the thread to halt it, and inside your `run` method check to see `if (Thread.interrupted())` is true (`interrupt()` doesn't immediately halt the thread, you've still got to check for `Thread.interrupted()`).  This way you avoid pitfalls like forgetting to declare your flag as `volatile`.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt%28%29

Short of encapsulating all of your computations in `Runnables` then putting them in an array and looping over them, which you've ruled out, Method 1 is your best bet.  As for how often you should check to see if your thread is interrupted, that depends on how long it takes your computations to run and how responsive you want your program to be to a Stop command - you can add several `println(System.currentTimeMillis)` statements to get an idea of the computations' timing, then add an `if(Thread.interrupted()) return;` every 500 milliseconds or so to halt the `run` method.

I wouldn't immediately rule out Method 2, however, as your computations don't need to have anything in common in order for you to put them in `Runnables`

```
private ArrayList<Runnable> runnables = new ArrayList<>();

runnables.add(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    // computation 1
  }
})

runnables.add(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    // computation 2
  }
})

// etc

public void run() {
  for(Runnable runnable: runnables) {
    if(Thread.interrupted()) return;
    runnable.run();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how your GUI is structured, is there any chance that you could throw an exception (probably an interruptedexception) from the GUI code that would blow out the long process?

The key thing is to look for *somewhere* in your code flow where things bottleneck to a point where a check could be inserted.  This may not be super obvious (for example, you could hook the repaint manager in a swing app) - and it is definitely not good practice in the general case - but for a very specific use-case, it may be appropriate.

If that's not possible, a slightly less verbose approach would be to use a method like this:

```
assertContinue() throws InterruptedException;
```

(or maybe call it ac() to keep the typing down).

you still wind up with cruft in your algorithm, but at least it's less typing.

Oh - and what are these calculations?  Are they blocking b/c of IO or locks somehow?  If so, then calling Thread.interrupt() will work...

Comment: They aren't blocking at all. I just don't want to put asserts all over the place, it looks awful. I think I'll have to do this anyways though. Thanks!

Comment: @CodeGuy How is your GUI code structured?  Could you put the check in the GUI calls?  That might be a good bottleneck.