# Java - stop a sleeping thread

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-sleep

In my java gui program, I have a button, of which upon clicking, will create a new thread that plays a song in the background.  Had I not created a new thread, and just played it in the actionListener, the song would freeze up the rest of the gui to be unusable until it finished.

However, I would like a means for the user to stop the song.. which in code I would take to mean 'terminate the thread'.  I've tried some online answers like the deprecated .stop() .interrupt() methods, but they don't seem to work.  I think this has something to do with the fact that the thread that plays the song is in Thread.sleep() for the duration of the song..  any way to terminate a sleeping thread?  -Thanks

Comment: There are a bunch of things you can make use of in the `java.util.concurrent` that might make things easier than dealing directly with a thread lifecycles. Will be hard to know without seeing any code.

Comment: here's an example of interrupting a sleeping thread http://stackoverflow.com/a/5915306/217324  interruption is designed to allow breaking out of sleep or wait states. if IO is involved that may complicate things, but sleep should not be an issue. i suspect you're looking at the wrong problem.

Comment: OTOH, if the thread has run, and the "music" is now in a buffer held by the OS, then you're going to have a tougher time stopping that.  Try to play the sound a little at a time so you can just not feed the audio any more bytes.

Comment: Thanks for all the advice (everybody who has posted) -- when I get back to my coding computer tomorrow, I'll try out the suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of sleeping, you could have your thread wait for an object to be notified with a timeout. You would then notify the object if you want the thread to wake up or interrupt it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion..  the way I've learned to multithread is like this:   Thread t1 = new Thread(new MusicPlay());  t1.start();  but then, how would I interact with the MusicPlay thread?  Like to call a method of the MusicPlay class from the original thread that would flip a flag variable within the thread playing the song from the original thread?

Answer (score 1):

You can use interrupt method. It will give interrupt signal to sleep method. you will catch `InterruptedException` and it will return from method.

Comment: This is the preferred technique, as it works for both sleep() and while doing most IO.

Comment: @user949300 I will work for both sleep and IO. Incase of any method processing just like while(true), then you have a variable isInterrupted by default its false, once you interrupt set into true. if its true break the loop.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the wait() and notify() function.

wait() tells the calling thread to give up the monitor and go to sleep until some other thread enters the same monitor and calls notify( ).

notify() wakes up the first thread that called wait() on the same object.

So you can keep another button like 'resume button' which triggers the event to notify().

Answer (score 0):

Make Use of **join method** in Main method of your java program.
join method waits for a thread to die.
Ex.

```
try  
    {  
        // waiting for thread t1 & t2 to complete its execution  
        thread.join();
        thread2.join();  
        
    }  
    catch (InterruptedException ie)  
    {  
        ie.printStackTrace();  
        
    }  
    System.out.println("T1 "+thread.getState());
    System.out.println("T2 "+thread2.getState());
```

op:
T1 Terminated
T2 Terminated

Or visit this code
https://onlinegdb.com/Cr1HMdpzcg

for more Multithreading concepts visit
https://www.javatpoint.com/multithreading-in-java