# What is the Interrupt Status Flag in Java and how does it work?

Tags: java, concurrency, interrupt

I'm new to Java and is trying to the concept of "interrupt status flag" as part of Java concurrency. I have read Oracle's official documents and tutorials on the topic and is still unclear as to what exactly is a "interrupt status flag" and how it works. Could someone please kindly provide me with some explanation?

Comment: It's a boolean state variable in the `Thread` class, set by `Thread.interrupt()` and cleared by `Thread.interrupted().` Nothing much to understand there, and it's well documented in both the Javadoc and the Java Tutorial. Either too trivial or too broad.

Comment: see [How can I kill a thread? without using stop();](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5915156/217324)

Answer (score 2):

It is a marker that indicates to stop thread.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(!Thread.currentThread().interrupted()) {
                System.out.println("Thread is not interrupted");
            }
            System.out.println("Thread is interrupted");
        }
    });

    thread.start();
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    thread.interrupt();
}
```

Comment: @dzjustinli If this answer satisfies you it is difficult to see what you didn't understand in the Javadoc or the Oracle Tutorial.