# Java Illegal Thread State Exception coding error

Tags: java, multithreading, exception

I have some code here and it seems to run into an `IllegalThreadStateException`and I don't know why. By doing this, it runs two codes at the same time. What I am trying to do is that if I enter anything (word, number, character) the countdown will restart. But whenever I enter something before the countdown stops, it always runs to that exception. What am I doing wrong and is there something I can do to correct it?

[These are two codes merged in one picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZw1P.jpg)

Comment: Don't use a picture for displaying text.

Comment: Please post your code and the stack trace here.

Comment: You are starting the same thread multiple times - you cannot do that (javadoc specify that it will cause IllegalThreadStateException). Next thing - do not use stop method - it is considered as wrongly written

Comment: Sorry, it can't copy paste my code to here.//

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't call start on a thread more than once. When you call start the second time you'll get an IllegalStateException.

Move the initialization of exp to within the for loop so that start is called on a different instance each time.

Comment: That actually works O_O TY TY TY TY TY!!!!

Comment: @user6345865: great. also check out [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5915306/217324) which has an example of how to terminate a thread using interrupt instead of stop.

Comment: Oh, is there a difference?

Comment: @user6345865: stop is deprecated because how it's unsafe, it releases all locks and may prevent the thread from cleaning up properly. interruption notifies the thread that it needs to end but leaves when it terminates up to the thread.

Comment: Oh I see. Thank you :)