# what's the keycode for power off button on blackberry

Tags: blackberry

I want to close the background thread when user click power off button.
The main screen is disappear when the button is clicked later the browser screen is appear.

how to stop the Ui background thread .

and

what's the keycode for power off button on blackberry.?

pls reply me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `(char) Keypad.KEY_END` keycode to catch power off button click.

In thread you can use `boolean isCancelled` flag with some `while` and `if` in thread code to interrupt it by setting `true` value. See [Using Threads in J2ME Applications](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/articles/threading2/). [Remember to clean up thread connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/837948/best-practice-for-killing-a-javame-1-2-thread)